# How to resolve No Session found for current thread

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I was trying to do generic way of implementation of DAO and I followed as per the [Article](http://www.codesenior.com/en/tutorial/Spring-Generic-DAO-and-Generic-Service-Implementation)

Following are my genericDaoImpl class

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Repository
public abstract class GenericDaoImpl<E, K extends Serializable> 
        implements GenericDao<E, K> {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected Class<? extends E> daoType;

    /**
    * By defining this class as abstract, we prevent Spring from creating 
    * instance of this class If not defined as abstract, 
    * getClass().getGenericSuperClass() would return Object. There would be 
    * exception because Object class does not hava constructor with parameters.
    */
    public GenericDaoImpl() {
        Type t = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) t;
        daoType = (Class) pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    protected Session currentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @Override
    public void add(E entity) {
        currentSession().save(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void saveOrUpdate(E entity) {
        currentSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(E entity) {
        currentSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(E entity) {
        currentSession().delete(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public E find(K key) {
        return (E) currentSession().get(daoType, key);
    }

    @Override
    public List<E> getAll() {
        return currentSession().createCriteria(daoType).list();
    }
}
```

**GENERICDAO**

```
public interface GenericDao<E,K> {
    public void add(E entity) ;
    public void saveOrUpdate(E entity) ;
    public void update(E entity) ;
    public void remove(E entity);
    public E find(K key);
    public List<E> getAll() ;
}
```

**SERVICE CLASS**

```
@Service
public class test {
    @Autowired
    TestPlanDao testPlanDao;
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public int saveTestPlan()
    {

        try
        {

        TestPlan tp=new TestPlan();

        tp.setTestplan_version(1);
        testPlanDao.saveTestPlan(tp);
        logger.info("testplan saved");
        return 1;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error(e.getMessage(),e);
            return 0;
        }

    }
```

This is my daoImpl

```
@Repository
public class TestPlanDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl<TestPlan, Integer> implements TestPlanDao{



    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void saveTestPlan(TestPlan tp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        add(tp);

    }
```

**hibernate configuration xml**

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://${mysqlHost}/${mysqldatabase}" />

        <property name="username" value="${mysqlUserName}" />
        <property name="password" value="${mysqlPassword}" />
        <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="20" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="30" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="-1" />
        <property name ="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
        <property name ="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
    </bean>

  <bean id="sessionFactoryConf"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>

                    <value>com.test.model.TestPlan</value>

                </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>

                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
  </bean>
```

I am not able to find the cause of

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:988)
```

Comment: have you annotated your `saveTestPlan` method of your dao with `Transactional`? you didnt include it in your question

Comment: @Apostolos yes I did but forgot to add in the post. Please check the updated question

Comment: i think you need to either put the `currentSession().save(entity);` inside this method or declare `@Transactional` the `add` method too. since it is calling another transactional method, you have to annotate that too. try this and tell me if it works

Comment: @Apostolos I have tried your way,still the same

Comment: Add <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property> in hibernate.cfg.file.xml. And use currentSession.save(entity).Try this

Comment: @Vaibs I have already tried with that but no luck

Comment: I think you are missing transaction manager . Add in cfg.cml    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"></tx:annotation-driven>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" id="hibernateTransactionManager">  .Add this and try

Comment: @Vaibs Still the same

Comment: @SpringLearner just tested a senario with the code from the url you posted. i added the transactional annotation and the entry was stored in Admin table w/o problems. i guess you are using Spring's transactional annotation right?

Comment: How are you loading your configuration?

Comment: @Apostolos yes I use spring transactional annotation. You can see my service class as well as my dao class in the post

Comment: @M.Deinum The configuration is loaded from the web.xml

Comment: Show us how the configuration is being loaded and also show the actual configuring (the thing containing a component-scan).

Comment: @M.Deinum Lets have a discussion [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44929/java-spring-jpa-php-jquery-javascript-beginners)

Comment: @M.Deinum I hope you have seen my configuration

Comment: I hope you havent missed `<context:annotation-config>` and a transaction manager defined. You havent updated your question with transaction manager as said in comments.

Comment: @VinayVeluri I have added as a comment because my configuration is very long

Comment: Possibly off topic advice - similar generic superclasses can be found in spring-data-jpa project if you don't want to implement that yourself (check [SimpleJpaRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.10.2.RELEASE/reference/html/)).

Comment: @PavelHoral My project is pure based on hibernate. We are not using jpa implementation of hibernate

Answer (score 6):

Did you try removing the following property :

```
<prop key="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session">true</prop>
```

I believe that Hibernate will close the session too soon and resulting in your error. Since you use Spring TransactionManager, let it close the session.

Comment: Ok, please update your Spring configuration in your post because we need to see it. 
In my answer I supposed that you have correctly define your TransactionManager like @Rupesh did in his answer.
With both his answer and mine, plus remove that `@Transactional` annotation in TestPlanDaoImpl which is unecessary it should works fine

Answer (score 6):

you need to add following code in your hibernate configuration xml file

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
     <!-- property should be wired with a Hibernate SessionFactory in your case it is  sessionFactoryConf -->
     <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactoryConf" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to remove the @Transactional annotation from the Repository method , use only the @Transactional annotation on the service layer method.

```
   @Repository
 public class TestPlanDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl<TestPlan, Integer>   implements TestPlanDao{



     @Override
     @Transactional //Remove annotation from here
    public void saveTestPlan(TestPlan tp) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     add(tp);

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove @Transactional annotation from function and use it on the class level.

Answer (score 1):

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactoryConf" />
</bean>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add some context, this will make your answer easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you try to save changes on a Business Object after a transaction has already finished.

I think you should take a look to Spring Data JPA ? It has a lot more to offer than a generic DAO.