# Committing an insert with Transactional decorator

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have the following save method which inserts and commits the object into my database:

```
 public void save() {

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(this);
    session.getTransaction().commit();

}
```

However, if I use the decorator, it never actually commits to the database:

```
@Transactional
public void save() {

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.save(this);

}
```

Is there something additional I need to do in order for connection to commit it?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I've taken a look at that. Which part specifically shows how to save to a database?

Comment: The entire first chapter shows how to do that. If your `@Transactional` isn't working, then you haven't enabled transaction management, you haven't annotated your class with `@Component` (or any related annotation), you aren't calling the method on a Spring bean, or a mix of all these.

Comment: @David542 https://stackoverflow.com/q/38397157/2664200 looks duplicate

Answer (score 0):

The `@Transactional` annotation will already create a transaction using a proxy.
So you don't need to open a new session from your sessionFactory, you just need to get the current one.
This should work for you:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrenstSession();
session.save(this);
```

Please let me know if it worked :)

Comment: no, this doesn't save anything to my database. Like in the question, I'm still having to start and commit the transaction. The decorator isn't doing anything with regards to actually saving the data to my database.

Comment: Sound strange, are you calling the method within the service?

Comment: no, I'm doing everything in my `UserEntity` class. I'm more trying to figure out how to create/update/delete objects, so am doing it all from one file.

Comment: I think that would be the problem, since Spring can only open the transaction if you call the method annotated with @Transactional from an another component/service

Comment: I see -- so I should create a new class called `UserEntityRepository` and put the save method in there and try it?

Comment: Yup, as the document said: "Since this mechanism is based on proxies, only 'external' method calls coming in through the proxy will be intercepted. This means that 'self-invocation', i.e. a method within the target object calling some other method of the target object, won't lead to an actual transaction at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with @Transactional!"..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174534/discussion-between-jiajie-xu-and-david542).